# How to Copy & Paste Formula from Merge cell with out skipping a column

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy the formula in a merged cell and paste to the next cell.
Since it is merged and contained 2 columns, the formula skips one column.

When I copy C3 and paste formula to E3, the formula shows like below.
[image]

However, it should be like this.
[image]
So the result should be this..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Insert a temporary, empty "dummy" column

Insert a temporary, empty "dummy" column between H and I **before** you copy and paste the formula. The values for "two" will now be in column J. If you now copy the formula, it  will see them as expected. Once the formula is pasted you can delete the dummy column, the formula will edit itself to look at column I.

This is a bit of a "dirty workaround" and may not always be practical, but it's just a consequence of the fact that your "formula columns" C and E have a column between them, and the "data columns" are next to each other.